# ssis lookup with derived columns?

Tags: .net, sql, database, ssis, lookup

I just want to make sure i am doing this correctly.

```
Derived columns:

car
truck


Lookup (after derived column:)

1.Query: select * from dbo.store where A = ? and B = ?.  

2.In column mapping/or advanced parameters I map car to A and truck to B.
```

Correct? I ask this because I keep getting an OLE error.

Comment: no one knows how to use a lookup??

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm waiting to hear back on the error message, my assumption at this point is that you are using the [lookup component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) incorrectly. Your query syntax presumes there will be a query executed for every row flowing through the component.

The way the lookup component works with default configuration is that during the pre-execute event, the query is run against the target database and **all** the results are pulled back. Which is why as a general best practice, you should only pull back the columns you need. The query results are then cached locally and used in the lookup task as a dictionary-style lookup.

These screens change between 2005 and 2008 but you can figure it out.

Select cache mode
[image]

Define connection and your source query. 
[image]

Wire up columns. This is how it will find matches instead of the parameterization method you were attempting. In this example, I am connecting truck and car to A and B and retrieving the foo column
[image]