# SSIS Migration - Pulling IDs from dest DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

So I'm working on migrating some data to a new server. In the new server, each entry in the MAIN table is assigned a new GUID when the transfer takes place. A few other tables must be migrated, and their records must link to the GUID in the MAIN table. Example... 
WorksheetID --- GUID
1245677903 --- 1
AccidentID --- WorksheetID --- Guid
12121412 --- 1245677903 --- 1

The guid is used moreso for versioning purposes, but my question is this. In SSIS, is there any way to pull the Worksheet's GUID from the destination database and assign it directly to the entries in the 'Accident' table? Or do I have to just dump the data into the source DB and run some scripts to get everything nicely referenced? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There's always the [Lookup transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx) No need for sorts to use it.

I seem to answer a few question on using the lookup transformation

- [ssis lookup with derived columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768025/ssis-lookup-with-derived-columns/7774607#7774607)
- [Excel Source as Lookup Transformation Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953531/excel-source-as-lookup-transformation-connection/7954984#7954984)
- [Using SSIS, How do I find the cities with the largest population?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080979/using-ssis-how-do-i-find-the-cities-with-the-largest-population/8082874#8082874)
- [SSIS LookUp is not dealing with NULLs like the docs say it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233766/ssis-lookup-is-not-dealing-with-nulls-like-the-docs-say-it-should/7236036#7236036)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using a Merge Join Transformation. You might need to pass your data through a Sort Transformation first before merging them.

Your inputs to the Merge Join Transformation will be the Accident table from your source data and the Worksheet table from your destination database. Just do the merge join on the WorksheetID.