# SSIS Change data on Import from Excel to SQL Server table

Tags: excel, import, ssis

I'm changing all of excel data to numbers before importing to my sql table with SSIS.

This is my original table.

[image: This my original table]

Need to achive this :

[image: This is my target table]

Is it possible to do it with SSIS?

Answer (score 0):

In your data flow, you need to provide a translation or mapping from your Source item's value to the target's value. This is generally accomplished through the use of a Lookup Transformation. By default, a Lookup will fail out if no match is found and will perform case sensitive matches so an `EX` value would not match `ex`.  An example of using the [Lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7774607/181965)

Since the lookup gives you the ability to write a query, if you don't have these in a table, you can "cheat" and write the query like

```
SELECT D.CutId, D.Cut
FROM
(
    VALUES 
        (1, 'EX')
    ,   (2, 'ZZ')
) D(CutId, Cut);
```